# Fetching more than 5000 items from SharePoint list using rest call

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

i am fetching more than 5000 items from list using rest call in SharePoint 2013, but it is taking lot of time. how to reduce the page load time.
Let me know if any information is needed.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to retrieve more than 5,000 list items due to performance and package payload times.

You should page the result set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d4b5c277-ed50-420c-8a9b-860342284b72.aspx#sectionSection6

Comment: Hope this helped. 

I know it's easier sometimes to just grab the whole list and do the filtering client side, but the realities of both the server perf impact as well as the large amount of data sent over the wire lead to you needing to b more judicious with your queries.

Comment: Thanks Steve Walker - MSFT